# Traversing a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Problem: Write a function called find_value that takes two parameters. The first parameter, called search_dict, is a dictionary. The second parameter, val_2_find, is a specific value to find in the dictionary. If the value is in the dictionary, it should return a list of the corresponding key or keys (if the value occurs more than once). If the value is not in the dictionary it should return the phrase "That value does not exist!".

```py
def find_value(search_dict, val_2_find):
    lst = []
     
    for k, y in search_dict.items():
        if val_2_find in y:
            lst.append(k)
        else:                 
            "That value does not exist!"       
                                             
    return lst
   
print(find_value({'key1': 'bird', 'key2': 'mineral', 'key3': 'animal', 'key4': 'animal', 'key5': 'animal'}, 'animal'))
```

Question: How do I return the Else without breaking out of the for loop?

Comment: You should use "==" instead of "in"

Comment: You can't. Why do you want to?

Answer (score 0):

y is not a sequence and assuming you want the exact match for the value "animal". The if statement should be as below:

```
if val_2_find == y:
```

The problem with **in** is, it is a membership operator and will also match extra stuff like "animals" when you are trying for "animal".

And to return from the else: just add as below. But note that The function execution stops right there. If you want for loop to continue you need to use continue as I specified in the commented line(uncomment it) and remove return.

```
   else:                 
        #continue
        return "That value does not exist!"
```

SO the complete code looks like below:

```
def find_value(search_dict, val_2_find):
    lst = []
    for k, y in search_dict.items():
        if val_2_find == y:
            lst.append(k)
        else:
            #continue
            return "That value does not exist!"
    return lst

print(find_value({'key1': 'bird', 'key2': 'mineral', 'key3': 'animal', 'key4': 'animal', 'key5': 'animal'}, 'animal'))
That value does not exist!
```

But if your requirement is to return the string only when the element is not found at all then the code should be something like below:

```
def find_value(search_dict, val_2_find):
    lst = []
    for k, y in search_dict.items():
        if val_2_find == y:
            lst.append(k)
    if not lst:
        return "That value does not exist!"
    return lst

>>> print(find_value({'key1': 'bird', 'key2': 'mineral', 'key3': 'animal', 'key4': 'animal', 'key5': 'animal'}, 'animals'))
That value does not exist!
>>> 
>>> print(find_value({'key1': 'bird', 'key2': 'mineral', 'key3': 'animal', 'key4': 'animal', 'key5': 'animal'}, 'animal'))
['key3', 'key4', 'key5']
```

Comment: y does not have to be a list. it can be a string. `in` works for strings as well. What you get as a response depends on what the input value is.

Comment: I agree **in** works for all the sequence datatypes. But my understanding is the user wants to do the exact match based on the example he has given,

Answer (score 0):

A few problems with your code.

There is no use of the else statement inside the for loop. It is not doing what you intended to do. You don't need it there. Once you have iterated through the full dictionary, then check if the list `lst[]` has any values. If it does, then return `lst` else return the string from the else statement.

The second problem is with using `in` instead of `==`. When you use `in`, values like `'wild animals'` will be counted as `animal` as `animal` is part of the string `wild animals`. If you want to be specific about `animal` only, then you have to use `==`.

Here's the updated code:

```
def find_value(search_dict, val_2_find):
    lst = []
     
    for k, y in search_dict.items():
        if val_2_find == y: #changed from 'in' to '=='
            lst.append(k)

        #removed the else statement

    # changed the return statement to return lst or string based on value in lst
    return lst if lst else "That value does not exist!"
```

You can do a list comprehension as well. This will do the trick. You can check for the value `==` (which will be only for specific match) or `in` for partial match.

This will check for value an exact match of `animal` as a value for any given key:

```
def find_value(search_dict, val_2_find):
    lst = [k for k,v in search_dict.items() if val_2_find == v]
     
    return lst if lst else "That value does not exist!"       
   
print(find_value({'key1': 'bird', 'key2': 'mineral', 'key3': 'wild animals', 'key4': 'animal', 'key5': 'animals'}, 'animal'))
```

The output of this will return as below

```
['key4']
```

Note: `key3` is `wild animals`, `key5` is `animals`

The below code is using `in` and will check for partial matches of `animal` in the value.

```
def find_value(search_dict, val_2_find):
    lst = [k for k,v in search_dict.items() if val_2_find in v]
     
    return lst if lst else "That value does not exist!"       
   
print(find_value({'key1': 'bird', 'key2': 'mineral', 'key3': 'wild animals', 'key4': 'animal', 'key5': 'animals'}, 'animal'))
```

The output for `animal` is:

```
['key3', 'key4', 'key5']
```

The output for `human` is:

```
That value does not exist!
```